# Converting red channel image to greyscale

Tags: python

I want to convert red channel image to greyscale image for thresholding .
But last line in following code  is giving an error..

newgray=cv2.cvtColor(new,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: (-215) depth == cv_8U || depth == Cb_32F in function cv::cvtcolor

```
   import cv2
    import numpy as np

    img = cv2.imread('t1.png')
    print type(img)
    img_gray = cv2.

  cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        new=[[[0,0,255%j] for j in i] for i in img_gray]
        dt = np.dtype('f8')
        new=np.array(new,dtype=dt)

        newgray = cv2.cvtColor(new,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: You need to post the error you 're getting.

Comment: You can't use a float64 type, you need to use a uint8 (CV_8U), or float32 (CV_32F). [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35472650/8944057).

Comment: Did the code you provided is the **exact** copy ? Because the indentation is all over the place and line 6 `img_gray = cv2.` seems to be missing something